# its succesfully uploaded to folder, but no data on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table name tbl_uploads (id,namalengkap,nik,dekripsi,file,type,size,tanggalupload), and upload.php below

```
 <?php
   include_once 'dbconfig.php'; //koneksi dengan database

   session_start();
   if($_SESSION['user']){
    }
   else{ 
   header("location:index.php");
}



 if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))

    $file       =rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc   =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size  =$_FILES['file']['size'];
    $dekripsi   =$_POST['dekripsi'];
    $file_type  =$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $file_nik   = $_SESSION ['user'];
    $file_namalengkap = $_SESSION ['user'];
    $folder="uploads/";
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)){
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,namalengkap,nik,dekripsi,tipe,size,) VALUES('$final_file','{$_SESSION ['user']}','{$_SESSION ['user']}','$dekripsi','$file_type','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        mysql_error();

        ?>
            <script>
                alert('successfully uploaded');
                window.location.href='home.php?success';
            </script>
        <?php

    }
    else
    {
        ?>
            <script>
                alert('gagal upload');
                window.location.href='home.php?fail';
            </script>
        <?php
    }





   ?>
```

what i want to ask is, i have succesfull uploaded file to a folder, but not in mysql, what i miss? 
when i var_dump its show me "bool(false)", 
what i should do to fix that?

Comment: `mysql_error` will tell you for certain, but I'd guess that the trailing comma at the end of `size,)` is probably the culprit.

Comment: i try that there is no error bro, what should i do? its been a day i try to fix that :3. the message from show just from var dump and its 'bool(false)',

Comment: Firstly, you're calling `mysql_query($sql);` twice; you can remove the first call. Secondly, change the second call to `mysql_query($sql) or echo mysql_error;` and see what you get

Comment: thanks andrewsi, yes i try that but the showing error is change to mysql_error bool(false), iam sorry but my skill is suck,

Comment: Could you edit your question, and include the code that you're currently using? Just the SQL parts?

Comment: i think the problem is on `move_uploaded_file` is returning false, because i use the var_dump on that, its that true? if it true why returning to false?

Comment: If `move_uploaded_file` was returning false, then you wouldn't be trying to run your SQL, and you wouldn't be getting your output from `var_dump`

Comment: oh yeah i get it, but why it cant upload to mysql? where is the wrong part of that code?

Comment: Update the code in your question to what you're currently using, with `mysql_error()` and everything, and I'll have another look.

Comment: what do yo mean like that? i use `mysql_eror` like that, but there is no error show,

Comment: You need to `echo mysql_error()`

Comment: oh im sorry, it show error "unknown column 'tipe' in 'field list' "

Comment: yes it solve, thanks a lot andrewsi, but i have a different question, could you answer again? i will post it soon, thanks alot andrewsi :D

Comment: And there you go - there's a typo in the SQL. It should be `type`. Note that you've _still_ got the trailing comma at the end of the field names.

Comment: please help me answer my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320833/how-to-save-2-data-from-mysql-on-session) andrewsi

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,namalengkap,nik,dekripsi,tipe,size,) VALUES('$final_file','".$_SESSION ['user']."','".$_SESSION ['user']."','$dekripsi','$file_type','$new_size')";
 mysql_query($sql);
```