# how to save 2 data from mysql on $_SESSION?

Tags: php, mysql, session

i have a table name users (id,username,namalengkap,nik,password,level) and ceklogin.php, below is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconfig.php';


$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$username = stripslashes ($username);
$password = stripslashes ($password);

$query =  mysql_query("SELECT username, namalengkap, nik, level FROM users WHERE username= '$username' and password='$password'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$level= $row['level'];
$user = $row['namalengkap'];
if ($level == 'admin')
{

$_SESSION['level'] = $level;
$_SESSION ['user']= $user;
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=homeadmin.php">';
exit;
}
elseif ($level == 'pengguna')
{
$_SESSION['level'] = $level;
$_SESSION ['user'] = $user;
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=home.php">';
exit;
} 
else {header("location:index.php");}

}



?>
```

i want to save 2 data on `$user['namalengkap']` and ['nik']
is this posible to do that?

Comment: You're escaping the same string twice `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);` and then again `$username = mysql_real_escape_string ($username);`

Comment: yes iam sorry, there was my mistake to delete that :D